# Microsoft Azure cognition services - Speaker Recognition - Rate Limit

Tags: azure, voice-recognition, rate-limiting

I use Microsoft Azure and the cognition service to be able to use the Speaker Recognition API.
I have a subscription "Pay as you go" with the Standard Pricing Tier (5 calls per second) . I use Unity to make the voice recording and to send the audio to the server.

Every 5 seconds, I send the audio to the server inside the update function of the C# script.
But around 30 seconds of speech, I got the error 429 : code: RateLimitExceeded,  message : Rate limit is exceeded. Try again later.

If anyone  use it, do you know why I got this response from the server, while I have a subscription to avoid this limit.

I joined the Microsoft assistant, and they told me that the subscription is active, but I don't see any direct debit.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the note in the readme section here https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-SpeakerRecognition-Windows,

Note: **Make sure that the number of requests per minute resulting from tunning the step size won't exceed your subscription's rate limit.**

For example, applying a step size of 1 on an audio file of size 1 minute will result in 60 requests. Applying a step size of 2 on the same audio file will result in 30 requests. For your convenience, we have provided sample audios to enroll 2 speakers and a sample audio for streaming. These audios are found under SpeakerRecognition\Windows\Streaming\SPIDStreamingAPI-WPF-Samples\SampleAudios.

Also, according to the API link on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/
The audio file format must meet the following requirements:

1. Container -  WAV
2. Encoding -   PCM
3. **Rate - 16K**
4. Sample Format - 16 bit
5. Channels - Mono

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply and I am sorry for this late reply. The audio file format that I sent follow the requirements. I try to understand but what is the meaning of "step size" ? I sent multiple audio files of 5 seconds each time. When I reach the sixth or seventh file, I got the "rate limit exceeded".  And I think that the subscription was not take into account but it is active.

Comment: As per the github readme.md, we can control the number of seconds between each identification request through tuning the "step size". That implies that step size is actually the number of seconds between each identification request. Hope it helps.